# Incorrect scope for eval

Tags: firefox-addon

I have [this code](https://github.com/Noitidart/Run-on-New-Window-Load/blob/master/bootstrap.js#L40)

```
eval(script);
```

where script is:

```
var script = console.log('xwin:', xwin);
```

however it keeps telling me that `xwin` is undefined, anyone know why `eval` is not taking the functions scope? Anyone know how to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with scopes or eval but that elsewhere in your code you call your "blah" function without passing a value for xwin.

See line: [109](https://github.com/Noitidart/Run-on-New-Window-Load/blob/master/bootstrap.js#L109)

Comment: No problem. Takes a 2nd pair of eyes sometimes :-)